# MIPS, registers, beginner

Tags: compiler-construction, mips

Just started studying MIPS, could someone explain a detail in this simple code: Here is the code:

```
main:

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0

    add $t2, $t0, $t1

    move $a0, $t2
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
exit:   
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

This is what I understand: `li $v0  5  syscall` -means to load immediately an integer that is read (in `$v0`? I think). Then I get the rest moving, adding...

When I start not understanding is when the line: `li $v0, 1 syscall` - comes up. This would have to mean to print a integer (from `$v0`?). How does it know to print `$a0` or `$t2`. How does this work?

Like this example:

```
 la $a0, str1
 li $v0, 4
 syscall
```

This would print the string from `$a0`. Why isn't another string printed, but specifically this one? Is the rule that the last string mentioned is printed (in this case.)

Comment: See https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html

Answer (score 0):

That's just part of syscall available services:http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html

```
main:

li $v0, 5 #read integer
syscall
move $t0, $v0 #t0 is the integer you intend to read

li $v0, 5#same as above
syscall
move $t1, $v0

add $t2, $t0, $t1 #add two integers and store it in t2

move $a0, $t2 # move sum to integer to print
li $v0, 1 #integer to print
syscall
exit:   
li $v0, 10 # terminate execution
syscall
```